# Kafka 8.2.1 - How should I use KafkaConsumer.poll - it just returns null?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

New to Kafka.

I'm using kafka 0.8.2.1 java library:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I tried to use `consumer.poll`  However it returns immediately.  When I look at the source code I see that it just returns null?

- Am I looking at the wrong thing?  is 0.8.2.1 not the right version for kafka 0.8?
- Is `KafkaConsumer` supported only after 9 release and not available in the 8 release?
- What is the most stable API for Kafka currently?  I thought it was 0.8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The consumer API with poll support is only available in Kafka 0.9 which is the last released version. For earlier versions you have to use the older consumer implementations under the kafka.consumer package in kafka/core.